# User-changeable pagination preferably using will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I am using the will_paginate gem and am trying to figure out how to make it so that the user browsing the site can change how many items he/she wants per page using a list, like the list on the right side of this picture   [image: https://help.gumtree.com.au/documents/1353285762.jpg]

(random google image search).

I'm also new to rails so I would very much appreciate it if you could give me an idea as to where each code would go. Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can use `jquery-datatables-rails` gem for pagination. For more information visit https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Gemfile

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

in your controller where you want to paginate

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @somethings = Model.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page])
  end
end
```

in your view

```
<%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([5,10,20,50],params[:per_page].to_i),
   :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `will_paginate` you would simply use the `per_page` option:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(
  page: params[:page], 
  per_page: params[:per_page]
)
```

However you should be wary when taking user input and passing it to a SQL query like this. In this case it it prudent to cast the input to an integer:

```
irb(main):008:0> nil.to_i
=> 0
irb(main):009:0> "gobeligook".to_i
=> 0
```

---

```
per_page = params[:per_page].to_i.zero? ? params[:per_page].to_i : 30
@posts = Post.paginate(
  page: params[:page], 
  per_page: per_page
)
```